# IE/Firebug Debugger. Is there a way i can find out JSP file name?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

How to see the which JSP file contains the given UI element like *textbox* in IE/Firebug Debugger?

Is there a way I can find out JSP file name? Even in firebug I don't see the jsp file name? In Internet Explorer debugger, when I do `find select by element`, it takes me to exact element source code. *But it does not show
up JSP file name* which contains this text box.

Say I am on any web page on internet explorer which contains some text box. *I want to know the jsp file name which contains this text box.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSPs are executed at server-side, and generate HTML. The browser doesn't know and doesn't care about the JSP. It goes to a URL, and takes the HTML from the response.

If you want to know which JSP generated some part of an HTML page, then discover to which servlet or JSP is the URL of the page mapped (provided this part is not generated by AJAX), and follow the path of the request from this servlet or JSP until you find the one that generates the given HTML part.

It can help to include a HTML comment at the start of every JSP, to be able to track that more easily:

```
<!-- Start of JSP foobar.jsp -->
```

This way, by looking at the HTML code, you just have to go up until you find such a comment to know which JSP generated it. But every JSP has to follow this rule.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on page and select "ViewPageSource" from the menu.You can find the corresponding jsp.